# What are benefits of slashy strings?

Tags: groovy

I can't see the benefits of slashy strings.
The groovy documentation says:

> ...with the added benefit of not needing additional backslashes to
>   escape special characters. That is especially handy with regular
>   expressions or Windows file/directory path names.

```
def s = /.*foo.*/ 
def dirname  = /^.*\// 
def basename = /[Strings and GString^\/]+$/
```

But the examples above are also ok with doublequotes except the dollar sign and backslash.
With doublequotes you have even not to escape the slash. So where are the benefits? 
Is it only the dollar sign and backslash that must not be escaped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the readability of :

```
def s = /<file directory="G:\Projects\Test\" id="a1">Something<\/file>/
```

vs

```
def s = "<file directory=\"G:\\Projects\\Test\\\" id=\"a1\">Something</file>"
```

You handle the `\\\\\\\\\`-hell more gracefully.

Comment: Are there any other benefits except backslash escaping?